# Why are log transforms used in measuring dose-time association?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

Explain why log(dose) and log(time) are used to measure the association between dose and time instead of the actual values of dose and time.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Perhaps a more suitable title could be given to this question?

Comment: If as appears to be the case, this is for some subject, please include the self-study tag, and check the [self-study tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and the last part of the first section of the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 3):

Demidenko, Williams, and Swartz (2009) is one example where *log dose* and *log time* are used instead *dose* and *time*. The authors provide a good explanation as to why they log transformed the data in their study.

In other words, this is a hint to do a little bit of reading.

- Reference: [Radiation Dose Prediction Using Data on Time to Emesis in the Case of Nuclear Terrorism](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2849647/) 
  Eugene Demidenko, Benjamin B. Williams, Harold M. Swartz.
  Radiation Research 2009 171:3, 310-319